# How to remove NA for multivariate time series in order to plot boxplot using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

i have a data frame containing "Dissolved Oxygen (a time series)" as shown below:

```
head(DO):
Month Season       site1   site2  site3   site4     site5 site6
1   Dec Winter       NA      3.0   0.00     5.60    4.1   3.8
2   Jan Winter       0.0     0.0   NA       5.70    4.0   6.0
3   Feb Winter       0.0     NA    0.00     3.30    1.6   5.5
4   Mar Spring       0.2     1.9   0.00     6.20    NA    8.5
5   Apr Spring       0.0     0.5   3.95     5.00    NA    7.7
6   May Spring       0.0     1.5   1.18     6.50    NA    5.9
```

I want to plot box plot using ggplot so as to see the variation across different sites. Note that Month and Seasons are treated as factors.
i used:

```
library(reshape2) 
DO.m <- melt(DO, id=c("Month", "Season"))
```

when i run the above code i got warning as below:

```
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped.
```

however i ignored the warning and tried to plot the data (as suggested by the forum) using:

```
ggplot(subset(DO.m, !is.na(value)), aes(x=variable,y=value, col=variable)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.size = 1) + 
    labs(title = "DO", x = "Station", y = "DO(mg/l)", color = "Station") +
  geom_jitter(alpha= 0.4, shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2))
```

the above code plots very abstract image which is not a box plot.
so how can i remove NA for all the sites from the melt data? your help would be appreciaated

Comment: try `na.omit(DO)`

Comment: you can just add the `na.rm=TRUE` parameter to your `geom_boxplot` call. In case you want more help, please provide the output of `dput(head(DO))` to demonstrate it with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing na.rm = TRUE to melt:

```
library(reshape2)
DO.m <- melt(DO, id=c("Month", "Season"), na.rm = TRUE)
```

As far as removing attributes and whether that might cause any problems, a dput of a subset of your data would be helpful. But regardless, letting melt pull out the NA values is probably the best place to do this.

I'd add a question as to whether you've inspected the different layers of your ggplot2, to see what they produce one at a time. For example, are you getting something when you just use your ggplot layer + geom_boxplot layer WITHOUT the geom_jitter

Comment: The problem was that value column in melt data was in character form (chr). i converted to numeric and used your suggested code and i am able to plot the boxplot. However  i encountered warning as:Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot). 
3: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point). Is there any wrong in the steps? or is it ok to ignore the warning message

Comment: Oh good!  I'm glad it helped! Please mark this as the answer and or upvote it if you were able to produce a boxplot by removing NA values this way. If you have another question about the warnings, go ahead and post that as a separate question, and I'd be happy to work that through with you!